# Is smpte170m Color Space Compatible with 10 bit yuv420p10le? Color Space choice(x265)

Tags: ffmpeg, video, encoding, colorspace, h.265

I need to encode a **smpte170m** color space MPEG-2 ("mpeg2video") video to **10 bit** **x265** (libx265, with **FFMPEG**).
Hoping to use **yuv420p10le**, but any suggestions are welcome.

Source video is in **smpte170m** color space and **NTSC**:

```
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=8
color_range=tv
color_space=smpte170m
color_transfer=smpte170m
color_primaries=smpte170m
chroma_location=left
field_order=progressive
```

Is **smpte170m** space even **compatible** with 10 bit such as **yuv420p10le**?

Should I keep smpte170m space or convert it to BT907 or other?

Resolution (after scaling) will be approximately **848x304**.
Which color space is more widely supported for such resolution?

Can FFMPEG/libx265 perform/compute correct color space conversion or it simply changes symbols in metadata without computing actual color conversion?

Encoded video is purely for personal use and will be played 99% of time on PC/android phones (No HDR screens at present).

Does NTSC standard still apply AFTER encoding to x265 or it becomes irrelevant? (say encoding to Matroska)

The only limitation I have in choosing a destination color space, etc (in encoded/destination video) is so that its play is supported in hardware on modern android phones/tablets/PC.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Is smpte170m space even compatible with 10 bit such as yuv420p10le?

There's no incompatibility - H.265 supports BT601-525 / SMPTE170m tagging. It depends on your player if colours are rendered correctly during playback.

So, first encode without any colorspace onversion and check. Else, convert to BT.709 using colorspace or zscale filter.